# 1.0.2 notifications of parent objects

Tags: realm

I want to receive a notifications when a property in the Parent object is assigned and have the notification result contain all the children that chaanged

Here is line of code I'm referring to:

```
realm.objects(Parent.self).filter("state = Error").addNotificationBlock { ... }
```

Currently I get the notification but I'm not able to tell what objects it applies to. Is this possible or do I need to go through each?

Thanks,
Mike.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation about [Collection Notifications](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#collection-notifications) on the Realm website, you can take the `Results` object from a query and assign a notification block to it. Whenever an object is changed in that result set (including new additions, modifications or deletions) the block will trigger with the specific index that was changed.

```
// Observe Results Notifications
notificationToken = results.addNotificationBlock { [weak self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
  guard let tableView = self?.tableView else { return }
  switch changes {
  case .initial:
    // Results are now populated and can be accessed without blocking the UI
    tableView.reloadData()
    break
  case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
    // Query results have changed, so apply them to the UITableView
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.insertRows(at: insertions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }), with: .automatic)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: deletions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)}), with: .automatic)
    tableView.reloadRows(at: modifications.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }),  with: .automatic)
    tableView.endUpdates()
    break
  case .error(let error):
    // An error occurred while opening the Realm file on the background worker thread
    fatalError("\(error)")
    break
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what you mean by children here. If that means you have a `List` property in your `Parent` object, you won't get granular index information on which children in the `Parent` object changed, but you'll still get the index of the `Parent` object itself that the child object belongs to.